# Firebase + Vue + Vuex: Keeping The User Logged In

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex

I am using Firebase with VueJS and VUEX.

I want to keep the user updated when I refresh the page.

What should I do?

Comment: You could start by reading [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are right. I should. I'll have a look at these documents as soon I can.

Answer (score 0):

I have put the logic in a vuex-mutation:

```
retrieveUser(state) {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user === null) {
      state.user.key = null
    } else {
      state.user.key = user.uid
      router.replace('/forum')
    }
  })
},
```

and I call it in the `beforeCreate` of my component:

```
this.$store.dispatch('RETRIEVE_USER')
```